# Migrate Eclipse project to Studio project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am trying to import an android project created in eclipse into android studio. This main project also refers to another library project in the same eclipse workspace.
When I import the main project into android studio, the library project is automatically imported as a sub-project (or shall we call it a module) within the main project.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i have android eclipse project , now i have convert that project into android studio project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer versions of Android Studio, the best way to bring in an Eclipse/ADT project is to import it directly into Android Studio; we used to recommend you export it from Eclipse to Gradle first, but we haven't been updating ADT often enough to keep pace with Android Studio.

In any event, if you choose "Import Project" from the File menu or from the Welcome screen when you launch Android Studio, it should take you through a specialized wizard that will prompt you that it intends to copy the files into a new directory structure instead of importing them in-place, and it will offer to fix up some common things like converting dependencies into Maven-style includes and such.

It doesn't seem like you're getting this specialized flow. I think it may not be recognizing your imported project as an ADT project, and it's defaulting to the old built-into-IntelliJ behavior which doesn't know about Gradle. To get the specialized import working, the following must be true:

The root directory of the project you import must have an AndroidManifest.xml file.
Either:
The root directory must contain the .project and .classpath files from Eclipse
or
The root directoy must contain res and src directories.
If your project is complex, perhaps you're not pointing it as the root directory it wants to see for the import to succeed.